# What's wrong with my dynamically built colModel in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So, I am using jqGrid and due to the nature of this project, I need to build out the colModel dynamically. Meaning, I need to build the model itself dynamically. I am retrieving data fine with my JSON call. 
So, I build an array of objects and then assign that array to the colModel property. No errors, but the data doesn't show up.... I am doing something very similar with colNames and it works fine. Does anyone see what I am missing? I have worked on this yesterday afternoon and all morning today and can't find any reason it shouldn't work.
 As you can see, it am assigning the siteVal array at the top of my code to the colModel property.

```
var siteVal = [{name: 'InvtId', index: 'InvtId', width:   20, editable: false, sortable: false, align: 'left', hidden: true}];
siteVal.push({name: 'Descr', index: 'Descr', width: 320, sortable: false, editable: false, align: 'left'});
siteId.forEach(function(site){
    curSite = site.substr(0,1)+"Val";
    siteVal.push({name: curSite, index:curSite, width: 20, editable: false, sortable: false, align: 'left', hidden: true});
})
siteVal.push({name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: false, align: 'right', hidden: true});
    var colData = ['', 'Description'];
colData = colData.concat(siteId);
colData = colData.concat('Quantity');
console.log(colData);
jQuery("#list3").jqGrid({
    url: 'OrdersInput.php?do=getdelvprice&state=' + $("#State").val() + '&city=' + $("#City").val() + '&FType=' + $("#FType").val() + '&siteid=' + $("#Plant").val(),
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: colData,
    colModel:  siteVal,
    loadonce: true,
    height: 525,
    width: 605,
    rowNum: 1000,
    key: false,
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    gridComplete: function() {
        $("#MsgDel2").html("");
    }
});
```

In using console.log to see the array right after I build it, this is what I get.

```
    {"name":"InvtId","index":"InvtId","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"Descr","index":"Descr","width":320,"sortable":false,"editable":false,"align":"left"},

{"name":"TVal","index":"TVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"MVal","index":"MVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"PVal","index":"PVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"DVal","index":"DVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"WVal","index":"WVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"BVal","index":"BVal","width":20,"editable":false,"sortable":false,"align":"left","hidden":true},

{"name":"Qty","index":"Qty","width":100,"editable":true,"sortable":false,"align":"right","hidden":true}
```

This looks exactly as I think it should look in that it completely mimics the existing code where the colModel is defined statically. The thing is this must be dynamic to account for future growth...

Comment: Did you get any error message in your console of your browser?

Comment: None at all. That is what has me so confused.. It seems that it would show an error if it doesn't load..

Comment: First of all you should always write which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version you used in your tests. Seconds you use `siteId` to generate `colModel`, but you don't include any data which you use. `name` property have to hold id rules (no spaces for example). Setting `index` in `colModel` is not required and is not recommended, properties with default values `editable: false, sortable: false, align: 'left'` can be skipped too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a real idiot..... I was copying text from another line of code and didn't realize that I had included the last attribute... hidden:true
So, of course it wasn't showing up as I was telling it not to show. Guess that is what I get for copying and pasting code.